# Problems importing MySQL data into Access 2010

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I have a small database with 10 tables in it - of those, 6 import directly into Access via an ODBC connection to a MySQL database without any issue. However, 4 of them throw an error: "Could not open the object"

The MySQL ODBC driver is 3.51 -- anything greater didn't work at all and it was suggested on the MySQL.com support site to use 3.51 instead.

I can also import these into Excel without any trouble... so I am not sure if the issue is with Access or the ODBC driver..

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue happen with MySQL tables containing field types that Access/Jet doesn't understand and that the MySQL ODBC driver doesn't fully translate enough for Access to map to a known field type (to Access).  I know it's been a bit of time - but do you think you could post a description of your table(s) that are having trouble? Perhaps you could get more MySQL/Access people in here answering your issue (if I can't, that is).